# Facebook API : Can't retrieve score

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using the Facebook Graph API with the PHP SDK.

I've logged in, with all permissions needed (full list is : `email,publish_actions,user_friends,user_games_activity`).

---

- When I use the scores API it seems to work (I got a "success" to true in return) : `$fb->api("/me/scores",'POST', array("score" => "5"));`
- But then, when I try to retrieve it : `$fb->api("/me/scores",'GET');`

  I've got this response (and the same from the FB Graph API Explorer) :

  ```
  {
    "data": [
      {
         "user": {
          "name": "Name_of_the_FB_account",
          "id": "FB_ACCOUNT_ID"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  ```

What happened with `score` and `application` fields (as specified in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/scores)) ?!

Comment: Could the person who downvoted the question explain why please ?

Comment: Probably someone who misread your question... Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out what was the mistake *(although it's not very clear in the documentation imo)*.

**I have to specify which fields are returned in the GET request.**

For example : `$fb->api("/me/scores?fields=score,user,application",'GET');`

Which returns :

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "score": 5,
      "user": {
        "name": "Name_of_the_FB_account",
        "id": "FB_ACCOUNT_ID"
      },
      "application": {
        "category": "Games",
        "link": "https://www.facebook.com/application-path/",
        "name": "ApplicationName",
        "namespace": "application_namespace",
        "id": "APPLICATION_ID"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

*By the way there is also `type` field in the documentation, which apparently doesn't exist.*

**EDIT** : As @YassineGuedidi pointed it out, this is a normal behaviour (but breifly documented) since [Graph API 2.4](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_changes)

Comment: This works like this since Graph API 2.4, see the "Declarative Fields" part of the [Graph API changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog)

Comment: thanks a lot. Although I am implementing this in Unity3D but this helped me out.